# regex bug while printing an ip

Tags: python, regex, subprocess, python-re

```
import re

text = "|2018-11-03 18:20:59.0|FrozoneMD|8607446f-5748-479f-b72a-e0d25c1c7757|70.19.66.12|"
ip = re.findall("(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)(\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)){3}", text)
print(ip)
```

The program searches a txt file and finds this line using regex:

|2018-11-03 18:20:59.0|FrozoneMD|8607446f-5748-479f-b72a-e0d25c1c7757|70.19.66.12|

When I print the var ip, it prints this:

[('70', '.12', '12')]

Instead of:

[('70.19.66.12')]

Comment: Since we don't have access to your system, why not remove the subprocess stuff and just show the string, in the interests of a [mcve]? (assuming the subprocess stuff is working OK, it's irrelevant to the problem). Thanks.

Comment: Does the format of the string change often? For example will the end always look like this except the IP changes? ```|70.19.66.12|```

Comment: The format does not change often, it will always look like that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `re.search()` and just print group(0), if there are any matches

```
import re

text = "|2018-11-03 18:20:59.0|FrozoneMD|8607446f-5748-479f-b72a-e0d25c1c7757|70.19.66.12|"
ip = re.search("(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)(\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)){3}", text)
if ip:
    print(ip.group(0))
else:
    print('none')
```

**Edit:**

If you need to get more than 1 matches, you can use `re.finditer()`

```
import re

text = "|2018-11-03 18:20:59.0|FrozoneMD|8607446f-5748-479f-b72a-e0d25c1c7757|70.19.66.12|\n|2018-11-03 18:20:59.0|FrozoneMD|8607446f-5748-479f-b72a-e0d25c1c7757|70.19.66.13|"
ip = re.finditer("(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)(\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)){3}", text)
for i in ip:
    print(i.group(0))
```

Output:

```
70.19.66.12
70.19.66.13
```

Comment: How can I print it in list format? (when there's more than one ip)

Comment: @NathanWilliamson I guess you can use python's list comprehension for that.
You can replace the for loop with:
```ip_list = [i.group(0) for i in ip]```
then just ```print(ip_list)```

Answer (score 0):

Your comment clarifying question made me beleive that this could be a possible solution.

```
text = text.split('|')[-2]
```

Comment: unfortunately this does not solve my problem

Comment: How come you say that?